# How to execute a java nippet from another one

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have the following classic java script.

```
public class HelloWorld3 {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }       
}
```

I just want to run this script from another script so that it just prints out `"Hello"`

this was my attempt to do just that.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       HelloWorld3 obj = new HelloWorld3();
       System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

which failed and I get why it failed.

Not sure how to do it right though.

Comment: Does your HelloWorld3 have a constructor? you shouldn't call a `main` method from another `main` method. Also, System.out.println() will print the toString() value of the obj, and will not run the `main`

Comment: "which failed and I get why it failed" so why it failed? And why are you trying to invoke static method from instance/reference instead of class?

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method is used to start a program, there is no need to have it in two different classes and to call one from the other.

To construct an instance of a class you need a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). Here's one:

```
public class HelloWorld3 {

    public HelloWorld3(){

    }
}
```

Now you can call `new HelloWorld3` from another class (such as Test) to create a HelloWorld3 type object. If you want this object to print a message, lets add a method to it:

```
public class HelloWorld3 {

    public HelloWorld3(){

    }

    public void printHello(){
         System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

You may now use this main method inside your Test class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   HelloWorld3 obj = new HelloWorld3();
   obj.printHello();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Modify the HelloWorld3

```
public class HelloWorld3 {        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }       
        public   void printMeStatic(String msg) {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
        public  void printMeInstace(String msg) {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
```

---

## Use it in other class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       HelloWorld3 obj = new HelloWorld3();
       System.out.println(obj.printMeInstace("a msg 1"));  //use this if you need an instance/ object of the class HelloWorld3
       System.out.println(HelloWorld3.printMeStatic("a msg 2"));   //use this for static methods (you dont need an object to use them)
}
```